# Custom JsonReader throws Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. on all objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm creating a custom `JsonConverter` to convert a property `"Type" : "A"` (or "D", "E", etc) to an enum that contains `Article`, `Disambuigation`, etc. Here is the relevant code in the converter class:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(SearchResultType);

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
    var typeProperty = jsonObject.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Type");
    switch ((string)typeProperty.Value)
    {
        case "A": return SearchResultType.Article;
        default: return SearchResultType.None;
    }
}
```

My problem is that it always throws an exception with message:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String.

I understand this to mean that it expected something like `"Name" : "Hello world!"` but got `"Name" : 123`. However, I know for sure that the properties it's failing to parse are strings. Is there a problem with my converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem with your converter.  Your converter is intended to read a string value from JSON to convert it into an enum value.  A string value is not an  object in JSON, therefore you cannot load it into a `JObject`.  Instead, you can  just get the string value directly from the reader:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var type = (string)reader.Value;
    switch (type)
    {
        case "A": return SearchResultType.Article;
        case "D": return SearchResultType.Disambuigation;
        ...
        default: return SearchResultType.None;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnyZaT

Comment: I see. So `ReadJson()` is invoked for every value within the object that's being parsed, is that correct?

Comment: No. `ReadJson` is invoked only for values that match the type the converter said it could handle.  As the deserializer is parsing the JSON, it sees that there is a property called `Type`.  There is a matching `Type` property in your target class.  That property has a type of `SearchResultType`.  So Json.Net calls `CanConvert` to see whether your converter can handle `SearchResultType`.  If it returns true, then `ReadJson` is called with the reader positioned at the value of the `Type` property in the JSON.  That value is a string in your case, so that is what your converter needs to handle.

Comment: Right. My bad, I forgot to specify getting called on every value for which `CanConvert` returns `true`. Thanks for the explanation!